# Flutter: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.name.name/com.name.name.name}: FLutter app keep stopping

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

Flutter logs:
E/AndroidRuntime(11852):FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11852):java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.name.name/com.name.name.name}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.name.name.name" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.portal.name-nCBiBcVsHFUgEAoWt_8Nbw==/base.apk"],

app/gradle file
`

> ```
> def localProperties = new Properties()
> def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
> if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
> localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
> localProperties.load(reader)
>     }
> }
>
> def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
> if (flutterRoot == null) {
> throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
> }
>
> def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
> if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
> flutterVersionCode = '1'
> }
>
> def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
> if (flutterVersionName == null) {
> flutterVersionName = '1.0'
> }
>
> def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
> def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
> if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
> keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
> }
>
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
> apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
>
> android {
> compileSdkVersion 33
>
> sourceSets {
> main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
>     }
>
> lintOptions {
> disable 'InvalidPackage'
>     }
>
> defaultConfig {
> TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
> applicationId "com.name.name"
> minSdkVersion 24
> targetSdkVersion 30
> versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
> versionName flutterVersionName
> multiDexEnabled true
> manifestPlaceholders = [
> appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.name.name'
>         ]
>     }
>
>     /*buildTypes {
> release {
> TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
> Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
> signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
>         }
>     }*/
>
> signingConfigs {
> release {
> keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
> keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
> storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
> storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
>         }
>     }
> buildTypes {
> release {
> multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
> signingConfig signingConfigs.release
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> flutter {
> source '../..'
> }
>
> dependencies {
> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
> def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
> implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
> }
> ```

````
android/gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

```
````

Comment: com.portal.name is your package name not com.name.name

Comment: yes, I know I hide it because it's confidential information